# Bonding / link aggregation, is it ok to connect 2 switches together?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, switch, bonding

I have 2 computers, each with 2 ethernet ports connected to 2 unmanaged switches using linux Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin). Can the 2 switches connect to each other without causing a problem?

It seems to operate fine and things work better when I artificially create some failures, but I wonder if it will cause some problem I don't notice.